# Whats possible in a for loop

Tags: c#, java, c, loops, for-loop

So today I went to an interview and one of the questions was the following (C# context).

```
//Print the output for the following code:
for (int i = 10, j = 0; j <= 10; j++, i--)
{
    if (i > j)
        Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
}
```

I have never seen such a construct before and having asked my colleagues, 4 of 5 at my workplace didn't know either *(Perhaps more a reflection on us but I digress)*. Using some basic logic, I was able to answer the question correctly but this knowledge has radically altered my understanding of how for loops can be structured.

So I guess my question boils down to this.

1. Do all C syntax based languages implement this functionality? IE: C, C++, Java, javascript etc.
2. Where does this syntax stem from?
3. Are there any other "not well known" structures that a for loop can take?
4. Is writing code like above considered bad practice given how hard it is to read?
5. Are there any good real world examples where such a structure is **required**?

Comment: I'm 15 years old, and I do use it sometimes for my own projects :D To me it sounds strange that your colleagues didn't know as well.

Comment: @Coline : there is still a question if one should use it ...

Comment: Can you do `j.ToString()`? I thought since `j` was a primitive, you couldn't access a method that doesn't exist. I suppose C# is different.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
for (statement1; statement2; statement3)
{
     /* body */
}
```

(1) First the `statement1` is executed.

(2) Next `statement2` is executed.

(3) If the evaluation of `statement2` is true then the body is executed

(4) Then `statement3` is executed.

(5) Repeat from step (2)

```
          |                  +<-----------------+
          |                  |                  ^
          V                  V                  |
 for (  (s1); -------->(s2 true? | false?);    (s3) )
 {                           |       |          ^
                             |       |          |
                             |       |          |
                             V       |          |
                          (body)-----|--------->+
 }                                   |
                                     |
                                     V
                                 (come out)
```

The structure you have shown is the same normal structure as above. The `statement n` could be any statement. In your example, you have separated by [comma operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in `statement1` and `statement3`. You can separate any number of statements by comma operators.

Generally `for` loops are used with the `statement1` with initialization as it is executed only once. The `statement2` is used for the loop termination condition checking, because the evaluation value of this statement is used to decide if to enter the body of break out. And the `statement3` is used for update of the loop termination variable as it is executed after the body. But generally they could be used in any way.

First `statement1` is `i=10, j=0;` this initializes the variables. Next in the `statement2` is `j <= 10` if this is true then the body is executed. After the body is executed, `statement3` which is `i--,j++` is executed. The loop will iterate `11` times `0` to `10`. But will print `5` times, as at one point `i` and `j` will become same and the `if (i > j)` will evaluate false.

**EDIT**
Here is an example where it might be used, not much practical but a sample use, to check for a palindrome string.

```
  int i, j, n, flag;
  char str[128];

  printf ("\nEnter string: ");
  scanf ("%s", &str);
  n = strlen (str);


for (flag=1, i=n-1, j=0; j<n/2; j++, i--)
{
  if (str[i] != str[j])
  {
    flag = 0;
    break;
  }
}

if (flag)
 printf ("\n\"%s\" is a palindrome");
else
 printf ("\n\"%s\" is not a palindrome");
```

We should always try to write code which is easy to read and which does not create confusion. This helps the code writer as well as others who read the code.

Comment: @Martijn, i'll help you coz i agree with you on the 'nice ascii' part.

Comment: thanks for that, but it would be good to know the cause of the downvote, i would correct it then.

Comment: isn't there anything nice except the ASCII ? i think the main issue of the asker was the comma separated syntax in the statements, which i have tried to make clear in the 1st paragraph after the 'nice ascii'

Comment: Phonixs Do you know [ascii-flow](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)? It will help you to draw ascii-chart... (**PS**: Don't vote me back I am voting after reading answers. I read it completely)

Comment: Yes seen the site, and it is interesting. But I have grown a habit of drawing manually. For complex diagrams don't use ASCII. (Yes, i know the SO culture and i adhere to it.)

Comment: I don't think C# possesses a comma operator in general (compared to C++)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I don't know about C# but the question was also tagged with C, therefore I have answered with reference to C.

Comment: Cool enough. I just submitted another answer for C#. The `for` syntax of the question is still valid in C#, but no comma operator exists in general; it is a special rule for the `for` statement, in C#.

Answer (score 10):

1. Java & C# both share this same syntax
2. The syntax probably stems from C/C++ which is the 'root' of Java & C#
3. Yes, you can also have zero initializers and end conditions for your for loop.
4. Whether or not it is bad practice really depends on how it is used. You can create quite cryptic code using this technique, however, it does not mean that when used correctly it is perfectly acceptable.
5. I doubt it!

Comment: beat me by seconds! the only part of the code i find suprising is that you can seperate arguments that increment by commas at the end. The initial coma syntax is standard to variable initialisation iirc.

Comment: 4. huh? With all due respect to Maxim and his colleagues, they were ignorant. Now that they've seen it, they won't struggle to understand it any more, so does that mean it's no longer bad practice? I get that it's somewhat bad to use constructs that are difficult to read even once you know about them, but I don't think commas in for loops are one of those. It seems wrong to me to prefer to avoid this rather than make your colleagues learn the language.

Comment: Your #4 is ambiguous at best. That _particular code_ can be considered bad because of the usage, not the syntax. Generally, the use of multiple variables is very acceptable and simple to understand (when appropriate).

Comment: Wiz makes a good point - in this case it would be clearer to use only one variable (say `j`) in the loop, and define the other as `int i = 10 - j`. So, OK, that code is a little fiddly, possibly I misinterpreted "code like the above" to mean "any code with commas in there", i.e. the thing that was was new to Maxim, rather than "this particular relation between the variables".

Answer (score 4):

In C and Java `for` loops you may specify an unlimited (or zero) number of comma separated initialisers (of the same data type) and end-of-loop actions.

The initializer section is really just one java statement; java variable definitions may be grouped if they are of the same type, ie:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
```

You can do what you like in the end-of-loop section - any number of statements separated by commas.

Since java 5, there is also the `foreach` syntax, eg:

```
List<String> list;
for (String element : list) {
    // do something with the variable element
}
```

The syntax works with `Iterable` types, which includes arrays and Collections.

Comment: Thought I should just point out that the multiple initialization syntax with the comma has nothing to do with the comma operator seen in the original question. It took me a while to realize which parts of the question you were answering :).

Answer (score 1):

1. Java supports this for structure.
   In other languages like C, you can have any expression instead of a condition-clause.
   This clause doesn't have to be related and could use different variables.

   ```
   for({declaration-clause}; {condition-clause}; {expression-clause})
   ```
2. The syntax is just an extension of the declaration and expression notations in C.

   ```
   int i = 10, j = 0; // a declaration
   j++, i--; // an expression.
   ```
3. Too many to mention.
4. It may be bad practice if you cannot determine what the code means.  In your case you were able to figure it out even if you wouldn't have written it that way.
5. A for loop is never **required** You can always replace it with a while loop so, no.

Answer (score 1):

According to my exp and research, this type of  'condition construct' is very commonly seen in image processing, say(really, say) you need to compare pixels between two images in (say, again) opposite directions.  Or even traverse neighbors in opp directions, too.   Another example, under this type of 'condition construct', when you need to convert a 32-bit bmp to 24-bit or vice versa. (only that the increment would be bit diff like i=i+4, j=j+3).

Answer (score 0):

output is:
0
9
8
7
6

---

1. Almost C syntax based languages implement this functionality.
2. Where does this syntax stem from c.
3. One part, two part, three part, all may disappear.do not have any part, loop can work right.
4. It is a bad practice.
5. I do not know.

Comment: think you got your `<` and `>` mixed up - the output is 0 1 2 3 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to 5, one common use is something like this (in C):

```
for (size_t pos = 0, end = strlen(something); pos < end; ++pos) {
    if isspace((unsigned)(something[pos])) {
        puts("contains whitespace");
        break;
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
for (size_t pos = 0; pos < strlen(something); ++pos) { ... }
```

`strlen` could be any operation that's expensive relative to the loop, such that it makes sense to hoist it. For `strlen` in particular *maybe* the optimizer could do it automatically, but in general if the compiler doesn't know what the call does, and you put it in the loop condition, it has to evaluate it every time around because it doesn't know whether it will change.

Of course, you could instead write this:

```
const size_t end = strlen(something);
for (size_t pos = 0; pos < end; ++pos) { ... }
```

So there's certainly no strict need for the extra variable to be defined in the for statement, and arguably there's a tiny advantage to making `end` const (or final) anyway, which you lose by defining `pos` and `end` together. Some people prefer the "loop variables" (in this case including a "loop constant") to all be defined in the for statement, though, since they "belong" to it.

Plus, before someone points it out, in my C example you don't need indexing at all:

```
for (const char *ptr = something; *ptr; ++ptr) { 
    if isspace((unsigned)*ptr) { ... }
}
```

but we can pretend we have a task where we are going to iterate using a calculated end point...

Answer (score 0):

In C# context (which my answer will only consider), there is no *comma operator* like in C++ and C, so technically referring to the comma operator is not correct for C#.

But the C# `for` statement was still designed to allow constructions that people already knew from C++.

The precise rules are to be found in **the section [The `for` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664753.aspx) in the *C# Language Specification***. We see that the third and last "component" in a `for (;;)` statement is defined as a *statement-expression-list*, and a *statement-expression-list* is defined, in a recursive way, as a list of statement expressions separated by the character `,` (comma).

So that explains the `j++, i--` part.

We also see that the first part in the `for (;;)` can be either a [*local-variable-declaration*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742.aspx) or a *statement-expression-list*. The first one can contain a comma as well. The declaration `int i = 10, j = 0;` is allowed as an independent statement (i.e. not inside `for`) as well, and must be interpreted as a *local-variable-declaration*.